# Windows Media Feature Pack not working correctly

Tags: windows, windows-media-player

I'm running Windows 10 Pro N on my desktop PC and I've installed the media feature pack ( http://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/download/details.aspx?id=48231 ) because it is apparently needed to connect to android devices via usb.

But when I open the Control Panel and browse to Programs->Enable/Disable Windows Features, media player features are missing entirely from the list.

Furthermore, when I open  (the new) Settings->Updates and browse to see the installed updates the Feature Pack for Windows (KB3010081) is shown. However, when I click on deinstall updates I see a new update list (in the old Control Panel) und the Feature Pack is again missing...

[image: Updates]

Do you know any way to install the Media Feature Pack properly?

Edit: To make it a little easier I've added an image related that shows the discrepancy between Settings and the Control Panel. Keep in mind that it is german though (I've installed the german version of the feature pack, but in order to make it simpler for english speaking users I've postet the link to the english version above)

Comment: That's the wrong update number.... current version of media feature pack is [KB3099229](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3099229)

Comment: Thanks but 3099339 does not seem to be installed on my system - the only update I can find (related to the Feature Pack) is 3010081.

Comment: Well, then download the right one.  I gave you the link...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Ben Voigt mentioned, I installed the wrong Media Feature Pack. The correct one is   [KB3099229](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3099229)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: All features showing up in Control Panel now?

Comment: Yeah everything is working fine :-)

Comment: For 1607 you should install this: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=aee1c16a-373a-4249-bbe9-4284b779f9c1

Comment: The above solutions didn't work for me after the April 2017 windows update, but this new one worked: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4016817/media-feature-pack-for-n-edition-of-windows-10-version-1703-april-2017

Comment: Note that _after the installation, a computer *restart* is mandatory_. I just shut down my computer after the installation in the evening and wondered why the feature pack didn't work next day, had to do a explicit restart to complete the update.

Answer (score 0):

You need the [correct version according to your Windows version](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3145500):

- [Windows 7 SP1](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=159730) ([KB968211](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/968211))
- [Windows 8](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30685) ([KB2703761](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2703761))
- [Windows 8.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=933e11b1-4135-42dd-941b-5209d2a37051) ([KB2929699](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2929699))
- [Windows 10 1508](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=a030bfe7-5d98-4893-b4df-428b677fe97f) ([KB3010081](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3010081))
- [Windows 10 1511](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=cb0ace3f-ab1e-46e7-a878-6fb1d285b40c) ([KB3099229](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3099229))
- [Windows 10 1607](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=aee1c16a-373a-4249-bbe9-4284b779f9c1) ([KB3133719](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3133719))
- [Windows 10 1703](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/E/C/9EC0EC2C-8151-468A-95A3-2F2AD6A2AC13/Microsoft-Windows-MediaFeaturePack-OOB-Package.msu) ([x86](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/E/C/9EC0EC2C-8151-468A-95A3-2F2AD6A2AC13/Microsoft-Windows-MediaFeaturePack-OOB-Package_x86.msu)) ([KB4016817](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4016817))
- [Windows 10 1709](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack) ([KB4039813](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4039813))
- [Windows 10 1803](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack) ([KB4057437](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4057437))
- [Windows 10 1809](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack) ([KB4134255](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4134255))
- [Windows 10 1903](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/mediafeaturepack) (KB entry missing)

Comment: I tried to install KB4039813, but discovered that I have already had installed it from automatic windows updates. Still I don't have the Connect app, the only feature from MS Media I actually needed :(

Comment: @Czar: I'm not familiar with the Connect app. Isn't it available in the Windows Store once the feature pack is installed?

Comment: Nope, it isn't. This app is supposed to make it possible to cast from e.g. an Android device to a Windows PC.

Comment: @Czar: Ah, I was actually looking for it as well, not sure if it is part of the media features.... (I thought it might have been discontinued with 1709)

Comment: That's a new feature only released in October. I don't think they'd discontinue it so fast and without replacement.